# Is it possible to create an instance-store AMI using the ec2_ami module?

Tags: ansible, ec2-ami

I am using Ansible 2.1.3.0 at the moment and I am trying to figure out how to make an instance-store AMI using the ec2_ami module.

It looks like it is not possible to do this if the instance has instance-store root - I am getting the `Instance does not have a volume attached at root (null)"` no matter what I do.

So I am wondering how could I make an intance-store AMI (using the ec2_ami module) from an EBS-backed instance? The documentation does not allow me to map the first volume to be `ami`, and second needs to be `ephemeral0`. I was going through the ec2_ami module source code and it seems like it has no support for this but I may have overlooked something...

When I do `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/` on the source EC2 instance, I am getting the following:

```
ami
ephemeral0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 2.2 and using `ec2` rather than `ec2_ami`, but this would accomplish what you're looking for...

```
- name: Launch instance
  ec2:
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws.secret_key }}"
    instance_tags: "{{ instance.tags }}"
    count: 1
    state: started
    key_name: "{{ instance.key_name }}"
    group: "{{ instance.security_group }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance.type }}"
    image: "{{ instance.image }}"
    wait: true
    region: "{{ aws.region }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnets_id }}"
    assign_public_ip: "{{ instance.public_ip }}"
    instance_profile_name: "{{ aws.iam_role }}"
    instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior: terminate
    volumes: 
      - device_name: /dev/sdb
        volume_type: ephemeral
        ephemeral: ephemeral0
  register: ec2
```

Pay special attention to the `instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior` param as the default is `stop`, which is incompatible with *instance-store* based systems, you'll need to set it to `terminate` to work.

Comment: I know how to create such EC2 instance. Problem however is to create an AMI! What I need to do is to create the `instance.image` in your task...

Comment: @DejanLekic sorry, I misunderstood, the error you referenced threw me off. I'm trying to accomplish the same, I've posted a new question here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394774/is-there-an-ansible-module-for-creating-instance-store-based-amis

Comment: @DejanLekic based on this answer here: http://serverfault.com/a/396686/135680  I suspect that since `ec2_bundle_instance` is Windows only, that the `ec2_ami` module is probably limited similarly on `instance-store` machines, so the process will likely need to be manually scripted using Ansible `command` tasks.